# calling an array method on a computed property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have an array:
`const arr = []`

I then have a computed property:

```
const filtered_arr = computed(() => {
 //...
}
```

I then have another computed property: `filtered_arr2` where I want to call `some()` method on the first `filtered_arr`.
But getting errors since `filtered_arr` is not an actual array.

```
const filtered_arr2 = computed(() => {
  filtered_arr.some((e)=>{}) // <- error
}
```

UPDATED:

Getting several errors :

1. `some is not a function`
2. `Container is not set or can not be properly recognized. Use container() method to set it`

I think my whole approach is buggy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [API documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#computed)...

> #### computed()#
>
> Takes a getter function and returns a readonly reactive [ref](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref) object

and

> #### ref()#
>
> Takes an inner value and returns a reactive and mutable ref object, which has a **single property `.value`** that points to the inner value

So with that in mind, you'll need to use the `.value` property within your setup

```js
const filtered_arr = computed(() => {
  // return some array
});

const filtered_arr2 = computed(() => {
  const isPresent = filtered_arr.value.some(...);
  // return some other value
});
```